# why two jquery functions are not working in same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using two jquery functions in the same page but only the 1st one is executing.What's the problem behind this? 
My code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$( "#anim" ).change(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "showAnim", blind );
});
});
</script>

<script>
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker(
    {
      minDate: new Date(1900,1-1,1), maxDate: '-18Y',
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      defaultDate: new Date(1970,1-1,1),
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: '-110:-18'
    }
  );                    
});</script>
```

Comment: Is there a reason for initializing datepicker in both functions?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? Datepicker options can be changed using the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are *executing*, but you only see the result of the first one, because the second one is trying to initialize a datepicker on an element that's already been initialized with a datepicker, and so the call is ignored.

It doesn't make sense to initialize the datepicker twice. Just do it in one place.

Comment: Can you show me how to combine this two into one initialization ?